# Case Fans in DC

Tags: power, 12v

I need to run about 15 12V case fans(80mm) from wall power. How do I do that? How much amperage do I need? Which voltage adaptor do I buy? I have searched this site and many other sites such as this and I did not find the answer. This is for a DIY project and I don't want to waste money if I buy incompatible parts.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Questions seeking for buying recommendations are considered off-topic. Furthermore, there are thousands of different DC fans, which have total different data. Nobody can tell you the correct adaptor without additional information.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I do that?

Buy an off-the-shelf power supply.

> How much amperage do I need?

Add up the currents of all the fans.  Or if they are all the same, multiply one of them by 15.  The current should be on the fan itself, or on the manufacturer's data sheet.  If you can't find that, get fans that do come with data sheets.

Add a bit extra for safety margin.  You don't want to stress the power supply.

> Which voltage adaptor do I buy?

12V - they are 12V fans!

Comment: Given the apparent skills of OP, you can also indicate that the fans should be wired in parallel, not series.

Comment: Wiring them in series won't do any harm, it'll only be a learning opportunity. :)

Answer (score 3):

You look at how much current each fan takes, sum the currents together and you buy a power supply that can provide this amount of current.

Comment: I would add like 10%, because nothing is perfect in electronics.Some fans might use slightly more, some power supplies might provide slightly less.